# Weird shift/lag result from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Consider this table a which contains person number, date (in year) and data.

```
a = data.table(person = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5), date = c(2010,2011,2012,2010,2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014), data = c(9,7,6,4,3,3,5,1,6,5,7,8,4,9))
```

I want to shift "date" by person so I do:

```
a <- a[order(date)]
a[, date := shift(date, 1L, type = "lag"), by=.(person)]

    person date data
 1:      1   NA    9
 2:      2   NA    4
 3:      3   NA    3
 4:      4   NA    1
 5:      5   NA    5
 6:      1 2010    7
 7:      3 2010    3
 8:      4 2010    6
 9:      5 2010    7
10:      1 2011    6
11:      3 2011    5
12:      5 2011    8
13:      5 2012    4
14:      5 2013    9
```

Which is correct, but when I want to shift another year by giving the same code again (I would guess the result would be like shifting date by 2 lags):

```
a <- a[order(date)]
a[, date := shift(date, 1L, type = "lag"), by=.(person)]
```

One would expect date 2013 in person 5, date 2010 with person 4, date 2011 with person 3, date 2011 with person 1 will be gone. This is **the desire (Correct) result**:

```
   person date data
 1:      5 2010    9
 2:      1 2010    7
 3:      3 2010    3
 4:      5 2011    5
 5:      5 2012    7
 6:      1   NA    6
 7:      3   NA    5
 8:      5   NA    8
 9:      4   NA    1
10:      5   NA    4
11:      1   NA    9
12:      3   NA    3
13:      4   NA    6
14:      2   NA    4
```

The weird output from doing the shift operation again gives:

```
    person date data
 1:      1 2010    6
 2:      3 2010    5
 3:      5 2010    8
 4:      4 2010    1
 5:      5 2011    4
 6:      1 2011    9
 7:      3 2011    3
 8:      5 2012    9
 9:      5 2013    5
10:      1   NA    7
11:      3   NA    3
12:      4   NA    6
13:      5   NA    7
14:      2   NA    4
```

It appears to be recycling observations?

Comment: If you want to do the shift operation again, you need to use a <- na.omit(a) first. Somehow it does not shift date again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your second reassignment and `order` call. `order(date)` places the `NA` values at the end. `shift` just takes a vector, and because `NA` values are now at the end, they're `shift`ed out instead of the `date` values you expect:

Alternatively, in your `order` call, you could use the `na.last` argument, i.e. `a <- a[order(date, na.last = FALSE)]`

```r
library(data.table)
#> Warning: package 'data.table' was built under R version 3.4.4
a = data.table(person = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5), date = c(2010,2011,2012,2010,2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014), data = c(9,7,6,4,3,3,5,1,6,5,7,8,4,9))

a <- a[order(date)]
a[, date := shift(date, 1L, type = "lag"), by=.(person)]
a[]
#>     person date data
#>  1:      1   NA    9
#>  2:      2   NA    4
#>  3:      3   NA    3
#>  4:      4   NA    1
#>  5:      5   NA    5
#>  6:      1 2010    7
#>  7:      3 2010    3
#>  8:      4 2010    6
#>  9:      5 2010    7
#> 10:      1 2011    6
#> 11:      3 2011    5
#> 12:      5 2011    8
#> 13:      5 2012    4
#> 14:      5 2013    9

# Note I'm not reassigning here, just showing for demonstrative purposes
# Notice NA placement
a[order(date), ] 
#>     person date data
#>  1:      1 2010    7
#>  2:      3 2010    3
#>  3:      4 2010    6
#>  4:      5 2010    7
#>  5:      1 2011    6
#>  6:      3 2011    5
#>  7:      5 2011    8
#>  8:      5 2012    4
#>  9:      5 2013    9
#> 10:      1   NA    9
#> 11:      2   NA    4
#> 12:      3   NA    3
#> 13:      4   NA    1
#> 14:      5   NA    5

# what you expect to see
a[, date := shift(date, 1L, type = "lag"), by=.(person)]

a[]
#>     person date data
#>  1:      1   NA    9
#>  2:      2   NA    4
#>  3:      3   NA    3
#>  4:      4   NA    1
#>  5:      5   NA    5
#>  6:      1   NA    7
#>  7:      3   NA    3
#>  8:      4   NA    6
#>  9:      5   NA    7
#> 10:      1 2010    6
#> 11:      3 2010    5
#> 12:      5 2010    8
#> 13:      5 2011    4
#> 14:      5 2012    9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: so by this it means shift() is stuck whenever it sees NA?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "stuck" - it's doing what it's supposed to do (shift a vector). I updated my answer as well, you can also use the `na.last` argument and set it to `FALSE` which would result in your expected behavior.